# Please tell me why this Magento 1.9 code is not working

Tags: mysql, cron

I am trying to get registered emails from one Magento 1.9.4 mysql table to another with this mysql cronjob below. The cronjob is executing but it looks like there is something wrong with the code as the emails are not being copied as required.

```
<?php

require_once "../app/Mage.php";

Mage::app();

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write_conn = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$query = "UPDATE `customer_entity` INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` 
ON `customer_entity`.`entity_id` = `customer_entity_varchar`.`entity_id` 
SET `customer_entity`.`email` = `customer_entity_varchar`.`value` 
WHERE `attribute_id` = 9 AND `customer_entity`.`email` IS NULL";

$write_conn->query($query);

?>
```

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/keqcre/public_html/mytools/cust_registration_email.php
```

I used this code above to call the cronjob.

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here or why the cronjob is not working.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked if your SQL query is working? I highly doubt it does.

Comment: Yes, the sql query worked perfectly from inside myphpadmin. The table is updated as required. Not sure if the location of the file has to do with it failing i.e. in /public_html/mytools/cust_registration_email.php

Comment: I am curious as to why you highly reckon the query itself will not work?

Comment: Because I couldn't see an obvious mistake in your PHP code. However, have you tried to run this manually using the php command?

Comment: Ok. Yes, I have. I have used a php connection script as a cronjob to execute the same query in myphpadmin and it worked perfectly but I will rather have it called within Magento itself (instead of via a cronjob).